# Remove whitespace between two single characters using gsub

Tags: r, regex, text, whitespace

I have a set of addresses that have state abbreviations like so:

```
a <- c("2 reads way wilmington d e", "30 rockefeller plaza new york n y", "400 university drive durham n c")
```

I would like to remove the extra space between the two characters in a such that the final result is:

```
a <- c("2 reads way wilmington de", "30 rockefeller plaza new york ny", "400 university drive durham nc")
```

I would like to use regular expressions to remove space between the two letter abbreviations and i was told gsub is best so I tried:

```
a <- gsub("^. .$", "..")
```

but I keep getting the literal string `".."` in place of, say `"ny"` like I want.  What's the best way to do this using regex? I imagine `grep` could also work?  Multiple methods are welcome.

Comment: Unless you are using an older version of R, you can simply use `trimws`

Comment: `gsub(" ","",a)` if at all you are trying to use `gsub`

Comment: just updated question, this is more like what i had in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foo <- c("2 reads way wilmington d e", 
         "30 rockefeller plaza new york n y", 
         "400 university drive durham n c")
gsub("(?<=\\b\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "", foo, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "2 reads way wilmington de"        "30 rockefeller plaza new york ny"
# [3] "400 university drive durham nc"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
gsub("[[:space:]]","",a)
```

Comment: What about space before or after characters?

Comment: just updated question.  i only want to get rid of the spaces between two single characters, not words

Answer (score 2):

```
sub("(?=.{2}$).","",a,perl = T)
[1] "2 reads way wilmington de"        "30 rockefeller plaza new york ny"
[3] "400 university drive durham nc"
```